# How do I write data to a temporary file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an original file that I need to copy to temporary.
I'm trying to do it inside the `Tempfile.create` block
But the file does not appear.

How correctly to create a temporary file?

```
dest_path_to = "public/medicine/reports/#{report_id}"
FileUtils.mkdir_p(dest_path_to)
original = File.open(pdf_path).read

file = Tempfile.create("report-#{report_id}.pdf", dest_path_to) do |f|
  f.write original
end
```

Comment: "But the file does not appear" - where do you check for it?

Comment: in `dest_path_to`

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Tempfile.html) (emphasis mine):

> If a block is given, then a File object will be constructed, and the block is invoked with the object as the argument. The File object will be automatically closed and **the temporary file is removed** after the block terminates. The call returns the value of the block.

If you want the file show up in the filesystem, for whatever reason, then don't use the block form of `Tempfile.create`.

Comment: I get the feeling that you're simply choosing a wrong tool for the job. What are you ultimately trying to achieve with this? Render the file as a web response, but with different filename? If so, you don't need any of these file copying schemes.